# How to disable persistent database connections for Drupal 7 / PostgreSQL

Tags: 7, database

I have a Drupal 7.2 + CentOS 5.6/64 bit + PHP 5.3 + PostgreSQL 8.4.8 (servicing unix domain sockets only) web site which often goes down on peak times because of too many postmaster processes started.

[On the advice from PostgreSQL mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/pgsql.general/browse_thread/thread/2fdc297392e0390d/21ce0df6a6023c79) I have installed pgbouncer at "port" 6432 with the following config:

```
[databases]
pref = host=/tmp user=pref password=XXX dbname=pref

[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
listen_port = 6432
unix_socket_dir = /tmp
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /var/lib/pgsql/data/global/pg_auth
pool_mode = transaction
server_check_delay = 10
max_client_conn = 200
default_pool_size = 16
log_connections = 0
log_disconnections = 0
log_pooler_errors = 1
```

And forced Drupal 7.2 to use it by changing  sites/default/settings.php to:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'pref',
      'username' => 'pref',
      'password' => 'XXX',
      'host' => '/tmp',
      'port' => '6432',
      'driver' => 'pgsql',
      'prefix' => 'drupal_',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Here an excerpt from /var/log/pgbouncer.log during peak times:

```
2011-06-20 17:32:48.591 23883 LOG File descriptor limit: 1024 (H:1024), max_client_conn: 200, max fds possible: 230
2011-06-20 17:32:48.591 23883 LOG File descriptor limit: 1024 (H:1024), max_client_conn: 200, max fds possible: 230
2011-06-20 17:32:48.592 23886 LOG listening on unix:/tmp/.s.PGSQL.6432
2011-06-20 17:33:48.593 23886 LOG Stats: 36 req/s, in 3346 b/s, out 57238 b/s,query 74605 us
2011-06-20 17:34:48.593 23886 LOG Stats: 43 req/s, in 3167 b/s, out 54435 b/s,query 68969 us
2011-06-20 17:35:48.593 23886 LOG Stats: 25 req/s, in 3391 b/s, out 42060 b/s,query 95764 us
2011-06-20 17:36:48.593 23886 LOG Stats: 25 req/s, in 3370 b/s, out 103636 b/s,query 72986 us
```

Also I've been advised to disable persistent database connections and have done it for my own PHP scripts.

But I don't know how to do it for Drupal, what would be the best spot for that?

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal does not use persistent connections.  See https://drupal.org/node/1079892.  You may need to lower the number of web server processes (e.g. Apache MaxClients).

Comment: Thank you and I've also put pgsql.allow_persistent = Off into /etc/php.ini just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

[Persistent connections are not be the only issue for pgBouncer transactional mode](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer#Feature_matrix_for_pooling_modes). You need to make sure that Drupal doesn't use `SET`/`RESET`, `WITH HOLD CURSOR`, etc.

Actually, I see that Drupal issues `SET NAMES 'UTF8'`, but maybe this is superfluous (so it doesn't break pooling).